# Where can I ask for a dataset of ultrasound images?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> I'm looking for an liver ultrasound images dataset for my academic project - liver diseases detection by ultrasound image analysis. Can anyone suggest where I can get it?

Is there an Stack Exchange site where this question would be on-topic?

Comment: Actually I agree with @rob looking at opendata's help page. Go post an answer already ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atul, the site you want is called [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).